# Nodejs : Cannot get route when using add.post

Tags: node.js, express

I am a beginner to Node and I am trying to create a multipage application with Mongo(mlab), express and nodejs. I am trying to navigate to a page `addUser` that takes `POST` requests. But I keep getting the error

> Cannot GET /addUser

when I use `add.post` on it. However, it does work when I use `add.get`

Here is `app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
const port = 3000;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://<user>:<password>@ds111882.mlab.com:11882/serene-brushlands-55292-db', function(err, database) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    db = database
    app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server started at port:'+port);
    });
});

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false });

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});

app.post('/addUser', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    res.render('addUser');
    // db.collection('users').save(req.body, function(err, result) {
    //  if (err) return console.log(err);
    //  console.log('saved to database');
    //  res.redirect('/');
    // })
    // console.log(req.body);
});
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is `addUser.ejs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>MY APP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/addUser" method="POST" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username">
    <input type="text" placeholder="specialty" name="specialty">
    <input type="text" placeholder="address" name="address">
    <!-- <input type="file" name="picture"> -->
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're gonna need to add a get for addUser:

```
app.get('/addUser', function(req, res) {
    res.render('addUser');
});
```

Comment: But that page has forms details that need to be submitted via post request, so shouldn't it be `add.post`? Also, I forgot to add the `urlencodedParser` parameter before, but I did now.

Comment: You need both. Get for showing the page and Post for the form

Comment: So are you saying I should add another method add.get(view, function) in addition to add.post(view, bodyparser, function) or does the `method=POST` in the form suffice?

Comment: Yes. You have to add both. One for 'NEW Action' (GET, addUser page) and another for 'CREATE Action' (POST, addUser form). To get more information about routing management, check 'Restful Routing' http://restfulrouting.com/